# Proxy ASP NET Core Web API requests to another API

Tags: c#, api, rest, .net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am implementing a REST API which has to do the following:

By default, all requests should be proxied to another API.

When i implement a new controller/endpoint in the new .NET Core Web API,
i want to be able to specify that requests to those endpoints should not be proxied to the other API.

Any tips/suggestions are appreciated as I'm very new to C# and .NET

Answer (score -1):

You could look into a web server like Nginx to proxy your requests to another endpoint